# How to select suitable journals for submission?

Tags: soft-question, journals

I think this post should be made community wiki, as there may not be some definitive answer, and it's more like a discussion.

My question is actually more subtle than the title of the post. What I wanted to ask is, how to decide which one of two (or more) journals with very similar qualities is better and more suitable to my paper?

Usually I look at several factors, including impact factors, advice from the people I know, members of the editorial board, topics of the papers published in the journals, etc.

Let's say we have the following hypothetical situation: we have a paper that we think it could be submitted to 3 to 4 journals, and we want to try the best of them first. But after considering all the above factors we still cannot decide which one to try first, because all these journals are equally good (similar impact factors, knowing one editor in each of those journals, willing to publish topics similar to our paper, etc). In this case, what other factors would you consider? Or simply try one of them and hope for the best?

Answer (score 9):

If there's a few journals that all seem roughly comparable just flip a coin or roll a die. It doesn't really matter as long as it gets published in a reputable journal. Debating between two or more similar journals is basically arbitrary.